# Python: sorting the lists of dictionary based on the indices of one list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have dict like the following:

```
dict1 = {1: [-1, 1, 2, 4, 3], 2: [11, 10, 9, 8, 7]}
```

How can I sort the lists in `dict1` based on the indices that would sort one of the lists. Such as the sorted indices of list

```
[11, 10, 9, 8, 7]
```

which is

```
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

So the new `dict1` will be:

```
dict1 = {1: [3, 4, 2, 1, -1], 2: [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]}
```

I have tried the code like this:

```
sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])
```

But still cannot figure it out? I can use a for loop to do this work but I believe there exist a more pythonic way. Any idea?

Comment: How you mean *based on the indices that would sort one of the lists*?

Comment: `[3, 4, 2, 1, -1]` doesn't look sorted

Comment: Are you looking for `dict1[2].sort()`?

Comment: Not really... How does `[11, 10, 9, 8, 7]` mean anything to `[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]`?

Comment: So `[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]` is the indices that would sort the `[11, 10, 9, 8, 7]`. It is returned by `np.argsort`

Comment: How are you using argsort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to compute the index list and apply it to all lists:

```
>>> dict1 = {1: [-1, 1, 2, 4, 3], 2: [11, 10, 9, 8, 7]}
>>> basis = dict1[2]
>>> indexes = sorted(range(len(basis)), key=basis.__getitem__)
>>> for lst in dict1.values():
        lst[:] = [lst[i] for i in indexes]

>>> dict1
{1: [3, 4, 2, 1, -1], 2: [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]}
```

If you're ok with "the first" list determining the order (you only said *"based on [...] one of the lists"*), you could also build columns and sort those:

```
>>> dict1 = {1: [-1, 1, 2, 4, 3], 2: [11, 10, 9, 8, 7]}
>>> dict(zip(dict1.keys(), zip(*sorted(zip(*dict1.values())))))
{1: (-1, 1, 2, 3, 4), 2: (11, 10, 9, 7, 8)}
```

Comment: Yeah. It works. The indices can come from any of the lists in the dict though. I though I could avoid using `for` loop for the sorting. But I didn't know the way of updating the dict I used here. Pretty smart. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: dicts are iterable

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I know. But why are you saying that?

Comment: Because you have `dict1.keys()`.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ah, right. Now I'm really torn. I do like short code, but in this case I also do like explicitly using `keys` because I'm explicitly using `values`. I think I'll keep it the way it is, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I don't think there is any need to compute the indices separately, just use the indices of 1 as the key and sort both times. I'll post an answer...

Comment: Well you don't really have a choice with the values but it would be pretty normal procedure not to call .keys

Comment: I'm torn on the issue of `keys` in this instance too - there is a symmetry to it that I like, but it generally isn't normal procedure. It does make the process explicit just by reading the code...

Comment: Ignore my previous suggestion. I am clearly underslept.

Answer (score 1):

Sort using enumerate to get the sorted indexes and just use the indexes to sort the other lists:

```
from operator import itemgetter
dict1 = {1: [-1, 1, 2, 4, 3], 2: [11, 10, 9, 8, 7]}

l = [i for i, _ in sorted(enumerate(dict1[2]), key=itemgetter(1))]


for v in dict1.values():
    v[:] = (v[i] for i in l)
print(dict1)
```

Or if you want a new dict:

```
l = [i for i, _ in sorted(enumerate(dict1[2]), key=itemgetter(1))]
new = {k: [v[i] for i in l] for k, v in dict1.items()}
```

Or if you don't mind tuples:

```
new = {k: itemgetter(*l)(v) for k, v in dict1.items()})
```

Comment: I think a better way to get the sorted indices is by: `indices = np.argsort(dict1[2])`

Comment: @JianliCheng, that is why I asked how you were using it, are you using numpy arrays or lists?

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham, As long as the lists in the dict can be updated. The reason I use numpy to get the sorted indices is just because it's more straightforward. But I didn't know about itemgetter, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) in a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> order = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>> key = itemgetter(*order)
>>> {k: key(dict1[k]) for k in dict1}
{1: (3, 4, 2, 1, -1), 2: (7, 8, 9, 10, 11)}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Andreas I provided links to relevant documentation that explain it very well. The code itself is very self explanatory so the official documentation will suffice.